# Change product Variant on basis of image click on Shopify Single Product Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, e-commerce, shopify, shopify-activemerchant

I am developing shopify store for my client and my client require product variant selection on image click basis.
please check image here
[image]

you can see three small thumbnails(one with black background selected and other two with white background).
clients wants that when a customer click on one of these three thumbnails price and all other variants on this page should be selected for clicked image variant.
Please guide me either it is possible or not. if it is possible how i can customize it and if it is not please give any references for this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, variants are selected from a drop-down menu. You might want your customers to be able to select a product variant by clicking a variant image.
You have to add two scripts to your template. Here's very simple step by step.
https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/select-variants-by-clicking-images